# Push Notification using GCM - PHP

Tags: php, android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to implement Push Notification using GCM,
Besically i am trying to send Notification to the GCM using my PHP server which will deliver it to my android application.

I have used code at [androidhive](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/)!

The device is getting registered successfully but i am not receiving any notification at my device nor anything is visible at Google console.

I am not receiving any response from the link used https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send or https://android.googleapis.com

Is there anything wrong in this approach?

Can anyone suggest me any authentic source for this?

Comment: What response you get in your logcat while running the app on device???

Comment: @Syed....did you solved your issue?..I am also facing the same issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Realizing that some people are facing issues implementing GCM. I have decided to post solution.

The example on [AndroidHive](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/) is working perfectly. Its just the matter of correct configuration.

Replace project ID in Android app. (You can get project ID from you google's console link i.e google.com/apis/console/#project:**xxxxxxxxxxxx**:access)

Replace Server API Key on PHP Server(config.php)
**Key for server apps (with IP locking)**.
You can get your IP from [WhatIsMyIP](http://www.whatismyip.com/).

**Key for browser apps (with referers)** will not work.

Comment: how can i set port no with ip